# C# Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core

In **.NET core** project, I changed the all projects name than after reloading all project that time many errors were showing approx **3225**. And mainly all errors are related to system namespace like

- `System.Object` not defined or imported
- `System.Boolean` not defined or imported
- `Task` does not exist
- namespace `ArgumentNullException` could not be found

How do I resolve all those errors?

Comment: Everything worked/compiled before changing the project names?

Comment: Are you getting this errors at compile time?

Comment: Yes, before changing the project names @CPerkins

Comment: Not Compile time @KeyurRamoliya

Comment: how about clean the project and rebuild? or close VS, delete bin/obj folders manually, then reopen VS to compile?

Comment: Removing `bin` and `obj` and rebuild should work

Comment: If clean/rebuild doesn't work, try reloading the projects in visual studio, this will give the project a chance to do a lot of work with getting dependencies.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

- close VS
- delete the `bin`, `obj` and `.vs` (may be hidden) folders
- manually run `dotnet restore`
- reopen the project in VS

That fixes most things.

Comment: Clean / rebuild should _do this_

Comment: Clean/Build after closing VS usually works for me.

Comment: cleaning and rebuilding was my approach. That didn't do it. So I found this topic on SO. And closed and reopened VS (VS 2019). Which did solve the issue.

Comment: This issue might be older but I suspect the implicit usings.

Comment: @Wouter this is not a `using` problem - this is the compiler itself having a bad day, hence the mention of "predefined" types. Using directives don't impact predefined types.

Answer (score 7):

I was hitting this in VS Code. In Windows Terminal, `dotnet build` and `dotnet run` ran fine, but I was getting the errors in VS Code. The delete/restore/reopen answer did not fix it.

It seems it was an issue where I had an outdated version of Visual Studio confusing the C#/OmniSharp extension in VS Code.

The OmniSharp log included something like this:

```
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        Located 2 MSBuild instance(s)
            1: Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 16.8.30907.101 16.8.3 - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin"
            2: StandAlone 17.0.0 - "c:\Users\foo\.vscode-insiders\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.16\.omnisharp\1.37.16\.msbuild\Current\Bin"
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        Registered MSBuild instance: Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 16.8.30907.101 16.8.3 - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin"
```

That version of Visual Studio 2019 did not have the .NET 6.0 SDK installed, and I couldn't find it in the VS Installer.

So I installed Visual Studio 2022 and the .NET 6.0 SDK as part of that install. Now my log looks like this:

```
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        Located 3 MSBuild instance(s)
            1: Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 17.0.31912.275 17.0.0 - "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin"
            2: Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 16.8.30907.101 16.8.3 - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin"
            3: StandAlone 17.0.0 - "c:\Users\foo\.vscode-insiders\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.16\.omnisharp\1.37.16\.msbuild\Current\Bin"
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        Registered MSBuild instance: Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 17.0.31912.275 17.0.0 - "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin"
```

And the errors are gone!

*Disclaimer: I work for Microsoft.*

Comment: Thanks! My problem was exactly that: my Visual Studio was outdated. After upgrading it, there are no more errors in vscode

Comment: This resolved my issue as well. Very annoying since the install took so annoyingly long.

Comment: I was facing the same issue. After reading this comment and Microsoft Docs, I realized that I had a old version of VS Code running alongside my visual studio and the Compiler was confused. I closed VS Code and restarted the Visual Studio. Now the Issue is Solved. Thanks.

Comment: I’m up to date but never had issue until recently. When I started creating a blazer project in .net 6

Answer (score 3):

In my case, Error List window had hundreds of errors. But when rebuild the solution, used to get the message Rebuild All Succeeded. And even the project was able to run. But entire code was in red.
Just closing Visual Studio and deleting vs folder did the job.

Answer (score 2):

Gazi's solution above solved my problem which was exactly what she/he described. I had tried updating VS, cleaning and rebuilding solution, restarting VS. Nothing helped. Removing the hidden vs folder at the solution level did the trick. Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

Just like *citelao* I've got this issue in VS code when created new .NET 6.0 isolated AZ Function using wizard.

In OmniSharp logs I had about the same.

Just in case, in order to see the omni sharp logs, you have to open 'output' panel, and there on the right click on a drop-down:
[image]

I did not want to install VS 2022 as my target was to work in VS code for this project. I found the answer here: [omnisharp-roslyn #2247](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-roslyn/issues/2247)

Basically the solution was to add omnisharp.json file in the project root with the following contents:

```
{
  "msbuild": {
  "useBundledOnly": true
  }
}
```

After that I've closed VS Code, deleted **bin** and **obj** folders and started VS Code back.

Answer (score 1):

1. close Visual Studio
2. delete .vs (may be hidden) folder
3. reopen the project in Visual Studio and the error is gone.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be caused by a circular dependency between projects in a solution.

error MSB4006: There is a circular dependency in the target dependency graph involving target "_GenerateRestoreProjectPathWalk"

Answer (score 0):

For me, the error message

> 'System.Object' is not defined or imported

was due to an additional reference to a .dll file that was added silently by the IDE into one of the .csproj files.

After removing this unnecessary reference, the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the suggested solutions and nothing worked for me. Even adding the omnisharp.json from here https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-roslyn/issues/1094#issuecomment-907733500

Here's what worked for me. First off my VS code was running the latest version and I think the whole issue is due to the OmniSharp picking up the standalone version of MSBUILD which in my case was 16.10.1. In the VS code settings search for Omnisharp and find the setting OmniSharp: Use Modern Net and select the option. A prompt to restart the OmniSharp server pops-up and just selecting that updated my OmniSharp settings to use 17.5.1.

Hope this helps!