# New C# project with vscode and I have intellisense errors

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I used command `dotnet new console -n Test` to create it, and and build it just fine by running command `dotnet run` and `dotnet build`.

But I get the error in the IDE, how do I fix that?

[image]

If I try do add a using System; on top it even errors on that:

[image]

Seems a bit strange as this would be the first line of a non minimal project (and unnecessary to shows something is wrong in the IDE).

Comment: You're using the new .net 6 minimal project. And have global includes. Vs code might not be configured to properly recognize that.

Comment: Does OmniSharp logs have any hints? You might want to look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69997978/1043380)

Comment: The quickfix is to add `using System;` as the first line in your file. The better fix would be something like JHBonarius mentioned above.

Comment: I did, it errors on that too :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With C#10 there has been introduced [global using directives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-10#global-using-directives). It might not yet be supported by Visual Studio Code, as C# support comes with an extension that last has been updated in August 21', so before release of .Net 6 and C#10.
See [changelog of C# extension for VS code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.csharp)

In the future you should see the changelog updated with C#10 support. For now you can use `Rider` and `Visual Studio` for example, as those IDEs support new featues.

Of course you can also create an application in older version of .net and continue using VS Code.