# Visual Studio 2022 v17.2.4 - Weird exceptions in .NET Blazor Server

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a .NET 6 Blazor Server application I have been working on for a while. Last night when I closed Visual Studio it updated to the latest version (17.2.4 at this time). When I came back to said project the following day and try to compile the project I get a bunch of weird errors (previously I had none):

> Error CS0116  A namespace cannot directly contain members such as
> fields, methods or
> statements    D:\Repositories\MyWebApp\MyWebApp.Web\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.SourceGenerators\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.SourceGenerators.RazorSourceGenerator\Pages_Sample_razor.g.cs    356

> Error CS0246  The type or namespace name 'await' could not be found
> (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
> reference?)   SuggestionApp.Web   D:\Repositories\MyWebApp\MyWebApp.Web\Pages\Sample.razor    67

> Error CS8802  Only one compilation unit can have top-level
> statements.   SuggestionApp.Web   D:\Repositories\MyWebApp\MyWebApp.Web\Pages\Sample.razor    89

The application worked perfectly the day before, but now I get 20 of these errors. I have not touched anything in the auto-generated files, nor did I make any changes to the blazor component in question **Sample.razor**.

I tried cleaning up the solution, I tried creating a different file none of my attempts worked.

My guess is that the issue is somehow caused by the VS update even though there was nothing about blazor in the [release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-notes#17.2.4). Am I the only one with this issue or is there a fix to this sort of problem that I am not aware of?

Comment: Sometimes the "Clean Solution" menu item doesn't always clean everything. Have you tried manually deleting the `\bin` and `\obj` folders and see if you can compile?

Comment: I tried deleting the bin and obj manually, but the issue persists.

Comment: Per [Marc Gravell's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52887440/458354) deleted `\bin`, `\obj` in all projects AND deleted `\.vs` folder, and rebuilt solution. But for sure this behaviour after updating to 17.2.4 is absolutely unacceptable. Dozens of solutions and hundreds of projects to manually fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason I was getting all these weird errors mentioned above is because blazor interpreted the indentation incorrectly. Here is the file that threw all the exception `Sample.razor`

```
@page "/sample"
@inject ICategoryData categoryData
@inject IStatusData statusData
@inject IUserData userData
@inject ISuggestionData suggestionData

<h3>Sample Data</h3>

@if (categoriesCreated)
{
    <h4>Categories have been created</h4>
}
else
{
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="CreateCategories">Create 
Categories</button>
}

@if(statusesCreated)
{
    <h4>Statuses have been created</h4>
}
else
{
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="CreateStatuses">Create 
Statuses</button>
}

<button class="btn btn-danger" @onclick="GenerateSampleData">Generate 
Sample Data</button>

@code {
private bool categoriesCreated = false;
private bool statusesCreated = false;

private async Task GenerateSampleData()
{
    UserModel user = new()
    {
        FirstName = "Florin",
        LastName = "Zamfir",
        EmailAddress = "florin@test.com",
        DisplayName = "TestUser",
        ObjectIdentifier = "test"
    };

    await userData.CreateUser(user);

    var foundUser = await userData.GetUserFromAuthentication("test");
    var categories = await categoryData.GetAllCategories();
    var statuses = await statusData.GetAllStatuses();

    HashSet<string> votes = new();

    votes.Add("1");
    votes.Add("2");
    votes.Add("3");
    votes.Add("4");     
    
    SuggestionModel suggestion = new()
    {
        Author = new BasicUserModel(foundUser),
        Category = categories[0],
        Suggestion = "Our First Suggetion",
        SuggestionStatus = statuses[1],
        UserVotes = votes,
        Description = "This is a suggestion created by the sample data 
generation method",
        ApprovedForRelease = true
    };

// For some reason blazor interpreted this as the end of the code block 
// hence the weird errors like "Type or namespace 'await' cannot be found"

    await suggestionData.CreateSuggestion(suggestion);

    suggestion = new()
    {
        Author = new BasicUserModel(foundUser),
        Category = categories[0],
        Suggestion = "Our Second Suggetion",
        SuggestionStatus = statuses[2],
        Description = "This is a suggestion created by the sample data 
generation method",
        ApprovedForRelease = true
    };

    await suggestionData.CreateSuggestion(suggestion);

    suggestion = new()
    {
        Author = new BasicUserModel(foundUser),
        Category = categories[1],
        Suggestion = "Our Third Suggetion",
        SuggestionStatus = statuses[3],
        Description = "This is a suggestion created by the sample data 
generation method",
        ApprovedForRelease = true
    };

    await suggestionData.CreateSuggestion(suggestion);

    suggestion = new()
    {
        Author = new BasicUserModel(foundUser),
        Category = categories[2],
        Suggestion = "Our Fourth Suggetion",
        SuggestionStatus = statuses[1],
        Description = "This is a suggestion created by the sample data 
generation method",
        ApprovedForRelease = true
    };

    await suggestionData.CreateSuggestion(suggestion);
}

private async Task CreateCategories()
{
    var categories = await categoryData.GetAllCategories();

    if (categories?.Count > 0) return;

    CategoryModel cat = new()
    {
        CategoryName = "Bug",
        CategoryDescription = "Report a bug"
    };

    await categoryData.CreateCategory(cat);

    cat = new()
    {
        CategoryName = "Feature",
        CategoryDescription = "Suggest a feature"
    };

    await categoryData.CreateCategory(cat);

    categoriesCreated = true;
}

private async Task CreateStatuses()
{
    var statuses = await statusData.GetAllStatuses();

    if (statuses?.Count > 0) return;

    StatusModel stat = new()
    {
        StatusName = "Completed",
        StatusDescription = ""
    };

    await statusData.CreateStatus(stat);

    stat = new()
    {
        StatusName = "Watching",
        StatusDescription = ""
    };

    await statusData.CreateStatus(stat);
    
    stat = new()
    {
        StatusName = "Upcoming",
        StatusDescription = ""
    };

    await statusData.CreateStatus(stat);

    stat = new()
    {
        StatusName = "Dismissed",
        StatusDescription = ""
    };

    await statusData.CreateStatus(stat);

    statusesCreated = true;
}
```

In the `GenerateSampleData()` method at the point where I put the comment in the code blazor interpreted that as being the end of the code block. At design time it did not show any errors. Once I try to compile it, it figures out that something is not right and throws all the exceptions.

I literally tried everything to fix it and in the end rewriting the method did the trick. I am surprised that replacing the file altogether didn't work even after deleting the `\obj` and `\bin` folders. I guess I will have to report this bug to Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

**Have you checked the build output?** Most often it will hint which file **[indicates FAILED]** to stare at until something becomes obvious. Takes me back to my PHP days...

Just my two cents but when I've run into this it's because I either accidentally added or am missing a character [ { , } , < , > , ; ...] in the markup or elsewhere, **especially when it's the razor.g.cs files** complaining.

As others have suggested, **cleaning the solution** or **deleting the \bin and \obj** can folders help.